# Weird padding issue encoutered in sticky left column of a HTML table that uses Freeze Table jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a HTML table in which the left column is frozen while scrolling through table. To achieve sticky column, I am using  [Freeze Table jQuery plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/sticky-headers-columns-rwd-freeze-table.html). Everything is working good except one very weird padding issue of sticky column. Well I am not sure it is due to padding but it's my guess as I couldn't figure out what is causing it.

At normal view:

[image]

When table is scrolled:

[image]

Clearly you can see the sticky column (Post ID) is expanded below. Not sure what is wrong here.

Please try my code and find out to help me.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tb_wrapper").freezeTable({
    // freeze table header
    freezeHead: false
  });
});
```

```css
#tb_wrapper {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

#customers_table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.column_company_heading {
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  color: #2585fe;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 250px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}

.column_heading_div {
  background-color: #d9e5f0;
  border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.customer_row th,
.customer_row td {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e9ee;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
  color: #545454;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.customer_row th:first-child {
  border-left: 3px solid #2585fe;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.customer_row td:last-child {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

.customer_row:nth-child(2) td:last-child {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
}

.customer_row:nth-child(2) th,
.customer_row:nth-child(2) td {
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://yidas.github.io/jquery-freeze-table/dist/js/freeze-table.js"></script>
<div id="tb_wrapper">
  <table id="customers_table">
    <tr>
      <th class="customer_row_heading" style="width:300px;">
        <div class="column_company_heading column_company">Post ID</div>
      </th>
      <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;">
        <div class="column_heading_div">Post Name</div>
      </th>
      <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;">
        <div class="column_heading_div">Post URL</div>
      </th>
      <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;">
        <div class="column_heading_div">Post Title</div>
      </th>
      <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;">
        <div class="column_heading_div">Post Heading</div>
      </th>
      <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;">
        <div class="column_heading_div">Post Content</div>
      </th>
      <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;">
        <div class="column_heading_div">Post Meta Keywords</div>
      </th>
      <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;">
        <div class="column_heading_div">Post Meta Description</div>
      </th>
      <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;">
        <div class="column_heading_div">Post Publish Date</div>
      </th>
      <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;">
        <div class="column_heading_div">Post Update Date</div>
      </th>
      <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;">
        <div class="column_heading_div">Post Views</div>
      </th>
      <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;">
        <div class="column_heading_div">Post Sort Order</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="customer_row">
      <th>1</th>
      <td>My Post</td>
      <td>my-post</td>
      <td>My Post Title</td>
      <td>My Post Heading</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
      <td>My Post</td>
      <td>My Post</td>
      <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
      <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
      <td>my-post.jpg</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="customer_row">
      <th>1</th>
      <td>My Post</td>
      <td>my-post</td>
      <td>My Post Title</td>
      <td>My Post Heading</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
      <td>My Post</td>
      <td>My Post</td>
      <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
      <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
      <td>my-post.jpg</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the `table` is cloned by the scroll plugin and that clone does not have the same styles applied to it as the `id` on the `table` element is removed.

To fix this, just change the `#customers_table` styling to also apply to the cloned `table` within `.clone-column-table-wrap`, like this:

```
#customers_table,
.clone-column-table-wrap table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Here's a fully working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tb_wrapper").freezeTable({
    // freeze table header
    freezeHead: false
  });
});
```

```css
#tb_wrapper {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

#customers_table,
.clone-column-table-wrap table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.column_company_heading {
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  color: #2585fe;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 250px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}

.column_heading_div {
  background-color: #d9e5f0;
  border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.customer_row th,
.customer_row td {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e9ee;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
  color: #545454;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.customer_row th:first-child {
  border-left: 3px solid #2585fe;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.customer_row td:last-child {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

.customer_row:nth-child(2) td:last-child {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
}

.customer_row:nth-child(2) th,
.customer_row:nth-child(2) td {
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://yidas.github.io/jquery-freeze-table/dist/js/freeze-table.js"></script>


<div id="tb_wrapper">
  <table id="customers_table">
    <tr>
      <th class="customer_row_heading" style="width:300px;">
        <div class="column_company_heading column_company">Post ID</div>
      </th>
      <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;">
        <div class="column_heading_div">Post Name</div>
      </th>
      <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;">
        <div class="column_heading_div">Post URL</div>
      </th>
      <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;">
        <div class="column_heading_div">Post Title</div>
      </th>
      <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;">
        <div class="column_heading_div">Post Heading</div>
      </th>
      <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;">
        <div class="column_heading_div">Post Content</div>
      </th>
      <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;">
        <div class="column_heading_div">Post Meta Keywords</div>
      </th>
      <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;">
        <div class="column_heading_div">Post Meta Description</div>
      </th>
      <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;">
        <div class="column_heading_div">Post Publish Date</div>
      </th>
      <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;">
        <div class="column_heading_div">Post Update Date</div>
      </th>
      <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;">
        <div class="column_heading_div">Post Views</div>
      </th>
      <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;">
        <div class="column_heading_div">Post Sort Order</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="customer_row">
      <th>1</th>
      <td>My Post</td>
      <td>my-post</td>
      <td>My Post Title</td>
      <td>My Post Heading</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
      <td>My Post</td>
      <td>My Post</td>
      <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
      <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
      <td>my-post.jpg</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="customer_row">
      <th>1</th>
      <td>My Post</td>
      <td>my-post</td>
      <td>My Post Title</td>
      <td>My Post Heading</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
      <td>My Post</td>
      <td>My Post</td>
      <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
      <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
      <td>my-post.jpg</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is with `table-layout:fixed` on `#customers_table` i have updated the snippet
>   and also some extra `div` closing tag and an extra `col` in table

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#tb_wrapper").freezeTable({
     'freezeColumn': true,
        'columnNum' :1,
        'columnKeep': true,
        'freezeHead': false,
  });
    });
```

```css
#tb_wrapper {
  max-width:960px;
  margin:50px auto;
 }

 #customers_table {
  border-collapse:separate;
  width:100%;
 }

 .column_company_heading {
  -moz-border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
  border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
  color:#2585fe;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding:10px;
  min-width:250px;
  height:20px;
  line-height:20px;
  margin-bottom:-2px;
 }

 .column_heading_div {
  background-color:#d9e5f0;
  border-left:1px solid #ffffff;
  -moz-border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
  border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
  color:#000;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
  height:20px;
  line-height:20px;
  overflow:hidden;
    min-width: 140px;
  overflow:-moz-hidden-unscrollable;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
 }
 
 .customer_row th, .customer_row td{
  background:yellow;
  padding:8px 10px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #e5e9ee;
  border-top:2px solid #ffffff;
  color:#545454;
  vertical-align:middle;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
    
  white-space:nowrap;
 }

 .customer_row th:first-child {
  border-left:3px solid #2585fe;
  -moz-border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;
  border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;
 }

 .customer_row td:last-child {
  -moz-border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
  border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
 }

 .customer_row:nth-child(2) td:last-child {
  -moz-border-radius:0 0 5px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius:0 0 5px 0;
  border-radius:0 0 5px 0;
 }

 .customer_row:nth-child(2) th, .customer_row:nth-child(2) td {
  border-top:none;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://yidas.github.io/jquery-freeze-table/dist/js/freeze-table.js"></script>


<div id="tb_wrapper">
      <table id="customers_table">
        <tr>
            <th class="customer_row_heading" style="width:300px;"><div class="column_company_heading column_company">Post ID</div></th>
            <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;"><div class="column_heading_div">Post Name</div></th>
            <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;"><div class="column_heading_div">Post URL</div></th>
            <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;"><div class="column_heading_div">Post Title</div></th>
            <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;"><div class="column_heading_div">Post Heading</div></th>
            <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;"><div class="column_heading_div">Post Content</div></th>
            <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;"><div class="column_heading_div">Post Meta Keywords</div></th>
            <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;"><div class="column_heading_div">Post Meta Description</div></th>
            <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;"><div class="column_heading_div">Post Publish Date</div></th>
            <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;"><div class="column_heading_div">Post Update Date</div></th>
            <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;"><div class="column_heading_div">Post Views</div></th>
            <th class="column_heading column_date_added" style="width:100px;"><div class="column_heading_div">Post Sort Order</div></th>
        </tr>
            <tr class="customer_row">
                <th>1</th>
                <td>My Post</td>
                <td>my-post</td>
                <td>My Post Title</td>
                <td>My Post Heading</td>
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                <td>My Post</td>
                <td>My Post</td>
               <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                <td>7</td>
            </tr>
          <tr class="customer_row">
                <th>1</th>
                <td>My Post</td>
                <td>my-post</td>
                <td>My Post Title</td>
                <td>My Post Heading</td>
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                <td>My Post</td>
                <td>My Post</td>
               <td>2017-07-21 13:58:16</td>
                <td>2019-07-30 22:38:36</td>
                <td>my-post.jpg</td>
                <td>7</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
```